# View extended stats for listening ports (using ss?)

Tags: netstat, ss

With `ss -tuiOp` we can view extended stats for an outbound process, e.g.:

```
tcp           ESTAB         0              0                                192.168.68.108:32862                     52.86.220.33:https     
 users:(("chrome",pid=13907,fd=44)) cubic wscale:12,7 rto:292 rtt:91.131/1.147 ato:40 mss:1288 pmtu:1500 rcvmss:1288 advmss:1448 cwnd:10 bytes_sent:25761 bytes_retrans:108 bytes_acked:25654 bytes_received:136601 segs_out:1010 segs_in:630 data_segs_out:407 data_segs_in:522 send 1.13Mbps lastsnd:2184 lastrcv:2092 lastack:2092 pacing_rate 2.26Mbps delivery_rate 339kbps delivered:408 app_limited busy:36036ms retrans:0/2 dsack_dups:2 rcv_rtt:33522.9 rcv_space:67624 rcv_ssthresh:225644 minrtt:82.525
```

However, this isn't viewable for listening ports using `ss -tuiOpl`:

```
tcp         LISTEN       0            64                                                     *:sip                                  *:*           users:(("linphone",pid=13355,fd=39)) cubic cwnd:10
```

Is there a way to get similar stats for listening ports? I'm particularly interested in bytes_sent, bytes_received, lastrcv.

Comment: a listening port hasn't transfered any data, so what kind of statistics are you actually looking for? Please explicitly name the things you need to know!

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe I'm misunderstanding the definition of a listening port then. What about nginx 8080, for example? It's receiving and returning data all the time. Is that not "listening"?

Comment: no, it's not. The listening socket isn't the one transporting data! the moment a listening socket gets a connection request, the `accept()` system call can create a new connected socket. the listening socket doesn't transport any data, it just waits for connection requests. the listening socket and the data-transporting sockets are two separate sockets.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks. Been a long time since I did c programming w/ sockets in uni!

Comment: Then let me copy&paste my comment into an answer - it seems to answer your question.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this one despite your excellent answer, Marcus, because the question itself bases off a false premise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listening socket isn't the one transporting data! the moment a listening socket gets a connection request, the `accept()` system call can create a new connected socket. the listening socket doesn't transport any data, it just waits for connection requests. the listening socket and the data-transporting sockets are two separate sockets.

Therefore, `ss` doesn't have much to show.